# Wordpress links broken after adding multiple posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a page called 'weekly offers' this page shows a weekly offer (obvious). There's also a detailpage. This detailpage shows some more information.

http://outletdokkum.nl/test/

If you click the orange button 'bekijk aanbieding' It says that there are currently no offers.

http://outletdokkum.nl/test/weekaanbiedingen/omo-xxl-pack/

This is because I've added two weekly offers in the 'offers' tab on my dashboard.
The posts uses a date for showing. If the date has expired the post will hide.

I've added two post. One with a date to 31 march and another with a startdate of 31 march. But when I add two posts the permalinks breaks. If I remove the second post, it's working just fine.

What could be the problem?

---

EDIT:

I am using custom post types for this.
My slug for the custom post type looks like: weekaanbiedingen

The fields that can be added to 'offer' are:

- Title
- Content
- Specs
- Old price
- New price
- Start date
- End date

When I set the newly created post to concept or waiting it works, but if I set it to published it gives the 'currently no offers' notification. But the current post works on the homepage, but doesn't on the detail page.

Comment: Can you put the post up that breaks the permalinks? Does it break *all* permalinks, or just some permalinks? It's probably a collision between slugs - either a category or custom post type slug is colliding with the slug you are posting.

Comment: I just set the second post as concept. It works now, but when I change it back to published and activated it breaks. I will set that up so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @cale_b Just activated the second post. Look at the second url. It's empty, only the title loads.

Comment: The second link works perfectly fine for me, as of right now...

Comment: I have a weekly offer where only 1 post can be showed at a time. But when I add a second to the dashboard (the first one will be shown) the link breaks.

Comment: "Omo XXL pack op=op
Helaas! Deze aanbieding is verlopen, uiteraard zullen er snel nieuwe aanbiedingen beschikbaar zijn."

Comment: How does "offer expired" equate to a broken permalink?  Broken permalink means the page does not load at all...

Comment: Yeah sorry, wrong name for it. How do we call this situation?

Comment: Hard to say.  Need lots more information.  Are these custom post types, or something else? What is an "offer" exactly?

Comment: Will edit my question. Wait a second :)

Comment: Edited @cale_b. Enough info?